# Weird thread issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, codeblocks

Alright im compiling the following simple chunk of code (found on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/)) on CodeBlocks IDE 12.11 with MinGW (downloaded separately and latest version too as of today).
The thing is that it shows the following errors upon compilation:

> 12: error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope
>
> 12: error: expected ';' before 't1'
>
> 13: error: 't1' was not declared in this scope

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void hello(void){
    cout << "hey there!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(hello);
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Are threads not supported by GCC completely?Do i need to add flags to my compiler, and how do i do it on a codeblocks project? thanks in advance

Comment: check g++ version. Look in the 'thread' header file to see if it defines the thread class.

Comment: Did you happen to notice the yellow exclamation sign at the top of the page that says it's a C++11 feature and may not be supported by all compilers?

Comment: @Vardhan g++ version 4.8.1. Also thread header file includes the class thread

Comment: @Brian i saw some of the answers in the other questions where they had gcc too and it still worked...

Answer (score 1):

Add `--std=c++11 -pthread` to your Compiler Flags

Comment: @CodeWiz94 I usually got this error when building without the `--std` parameter. Is it C++ project being built with g++?

Comment: @prajmus i tried compiling it as separate file, as well as in a project (GLUT) both with the above flags... and didnt work. Is there another way to include threads in my program?

Comment: I was under the impression `<thread>` in c++11 effectively replaces pthread.  What does pthread have that thread doesn't?

Comment: @Namfuak it's just a g++ option, it has nothing to do with headers. Also I think there's no info how `<thread>` is implemented.

Comment: @prajmus <pthread.h> is indeed a header, which is included using the -pthread option.  I was under the impression that you only need -pthread if you are using that specific header, not for all multithreading.
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html